# How to merge data to one line

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in a PostgreSQL database in the following format:

```
unique_key    category    date_period    value
```

So for example.

```
agriculture_all        agriculture    2021    15
agriculture_partial    agriculture    2021    10
science_all            science        2021    83
science_partial        science        2021    32
```

The query I want to run is to `GROUP BY` based on `category` and `date_period`, but then to display the values next to each other.

```
**[query here]**
output:
category       date_period    all    partial
agriculture    2021           15     10
science        2021           83     32
```

It feels like a really simple request but I'm struggling to get it working right in SQL. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use simple query using `sum` with `filter`:

```
select 
    category,
    sum(value) filter (where unique_key like '%_all') all,
    sum(value) filter (where unique_key like '%_partial') partial
from tbl
group by category;
```

[PostgreSQL sum filter fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=64b96c5782ef093580acd19095a1ad67&php_version=null&sql_version=psql14)

For prevent `null` values `coalesce` function may by applied:

```
select 
    category,
    coalesce(sum(value) filter (where unique_key like '%_all'), 0) all,
    coalesce(sum(value) filter (where unique_key like '%_partial'), 0) partial
from tbl
group by category;
```

[PostgreSQL coalesce filter](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=eac1d38e9a7260f7d964678c4033aa60&php_version=null&sql_version=psql14)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression...

```
    with partial as
    (select category, date_period, value
     from t1
     where unique_key ilike '%partial%'
    )
    select a.category, 
      a.date_period, 
      a.value as all, 
      coalesce(p.value, 0) as partial
    from t1 a
    left join partial p
      on p.category = a.category
     and p.date_period = a.date_period
    where a.unique_key ilike '%all%'
```

db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nr7isgotANmosAtw4JUJTG/1)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of conditional aggregation will do the trick.

```
SELECT 
  t.category
, t.date_period
, SUM(CASE WHEN t.unique_key LIKE '%\_all' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS "all"
, SUM(CASE WHEN t.unique_key LIKE '%\_partial' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS "partial"
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY t.category, t.date_period
ORDER BY t.category, t.date_period
```

> ```
> category    | date_period | all | partial
> :---------- | ----------: | --: | ------:
> agriculture |        2021 |  15 |      10
> science     |        2021 |  83 |      32
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b2362b06f7786d4786a3cb88f61d2b7d)*